# Angular.js controller that uses multiple services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I can't seem to figure how to inject multiple services into a controller.
I have listed my files here:

index.html file:

```
<script src="'./angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="'./angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>
<script src='./app/app.js'></script>
<script src='./app/welcome/welcome.js'></script>
<script src='./app/controls/questions.js'></script>
<script src='./app/services/questionsdata.js'></script>
<script src='./app/services/getsong.js'></script>
```

console.log error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=getsongProvider%20%3C-%20getsong%20%3C-%20QuestionsCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:43:7
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:43:69
    at d (http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at e (http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:41:1)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:41:364)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/angular/angular.min.js:87:42
    at link (http://localhost:8000/static/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26) <section class="container-fluid ng-scope" id="main" ng-view="">
```

My app.js file:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.welcome', 'myApp.questions' ])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: '/welcome'
            })
            .when('/welcome', {
                templateUrl: 'static/app/welcome/welcome.html',
                controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
            })
            .when('/questions', {
                //templateUrl: 'static/app/questions/questions.html',
                templateUrl: 'static/app/views/questions.html',
                //controllerAs: 'question',
                controller: 'QuestionsCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise('/')
    });

})();
```

My controller file:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
        .controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionCtrl);

    function QuestionCtrl(questionsdata,getsong) {

        var vm = this;

        var data = {
            params: "1,1"
        }; 
....
```

My `questionsdata` (first service) file:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions')
        .factory('questionsdata', questionsdata);

    function questionsdata() {

        var service = {
            getQuestions: getQuestions
        };


        return service;
.....
```

My `get song` (second service) file

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions')
        .factory('getsong',getsong);

    function getsong($http, $window, $interval) {

        var service = {
            getId: getId,
            getMySong: getMySong
        };

        return service;
....
```

That's ain't working.

When I change my controller file to use only the `questionsdata` service as follows:

```
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
        .controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionCtrl);

    function QuestionCtrl(questionsdata) {
```

It's working well. But when trying to use only the `get song` service as follows:

```
 'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
        .controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionCtrl);

    function QuestionCtrl(getsong) {
```

It ain't working as well.
Weird, right? What am I missing?

Comment: are you getting any error in console? also do update question with more information please

Comment: need his index.html where he is injecting scripts as well.

Comment: @PankajParkar  

updated my questions

Answer (score 2):

Try using the inject method:

```
 'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.questions', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
        .controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionCtrl);

    QuestionCtrl.$inject = ['getsong', 'questiondata'];

    function QuestionCtrl(getsong, questiondata){
```

Comment: how can this will fix things?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **index.html**:

```
<script src="'./angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="'./angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>

<script src='./app/controls/questions.js'></script>
<script src='./app/welcome/welcome.js'></script>
<script src='./app/app.js'></script>    
<script src='./app/services/getsong.js'></script>
<script src='./app/services/questionsdata.js'></script>
```

Because `myApp` depends on `myApp.welcome` and `myApp.questions`, so you have to put them first.